# Customize SSRS report on the fly

Tags: sql-server-2005, reportingservices-2005, reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

We have a requirement to represent the data on SSRS report in a simple manner.
i.e. the sql query for this report will look like this.

**Select col1, col2,....col8 from Table where Date between date1 and date2.**
So the user will run this report by selecting it from the web application with some parameters (eg: date1 and date2)
But the critical thing which i am facing here is that on the interface user has the option to select the **order** of the columns to position as shown in the image below.
[image]

In the image you will see the customized format has col1,col4,col8,col6,col5,col3,col7,col2.

Please help me how to create an RDL file to organize this kind of requirement.  Thank you in advance in understand the correct requirement and producing the result as requested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the expression for the columns to choose among the different fields depending on the selected parameter. For example, the expression for the value of the second cell might be similar to

```
=IIF(Parameters!MyColumnParameter.Value = "Choice1", Fields!Col2.Value, Fields!Col4.Value)
```

(Above code not tested, but hopefully close enough to give you the idea.)

Comment: Thanks Jamie!!!
It is quite helpful, I am using the iif condition for all the columns to display the values depending on the user choices..